# Order x amount of rows by different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alot of people ask about ordering by a column and then if rows are equal order by another column. 
However I'm wondering if it possible to order lets say 10 rows by a column and then for instance order the rest by another column

I'm thinking if there's anything similar to this that's possible?

```
ORDER BY column1 limit 10, column2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but it requires extra calculations.  Here is one method:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1) <= 10
               THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1)
               ELSE 11
          END),
         column2
```

Comment: Thanks alot, worked just the way i was looking for! :)